# What am I doing wrong? please

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong?

```
num = []
inp = raw_input("please enter a series of numbers separated by a space\n")
num = [ int(i) for i in inp.split()]
print(num)

quit_program = input("Would you like the average or would you like to quit?")
if quit_program == quit:
  quit()
elif quit_program == average:
  print mean(num)
```

It keeps saying this

```
quit_program = input("Would you like the average or would you like to quit?")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'average' is not defined
```

Comment: You have not defined the variable `average`.

Comment: Yes, because there is not `average` variable defined. And `quit` in `if quit_program == quit:` refers to the *function* `quit()`

Comment: I suppose you mean "quit" and "average" as strings, so those should be in quotation marks.

Comment: Yh I know I want it to quit

Comment: I think you mean `if quit_program == 'quit':` and `elif quit_program == 'average':`

Comment: Who was that a response to? No one is telling you you want to quit, people are explaining why your code is wrong.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I think he means he wants the program to quit. I think.

Comment: I put quotation marks in but still nothing

Comment: juanpa lool I was talking to the 2nd comment

Comment: What does "nothing" mean. That isn't an adequate description of a problem.

Comment: Right, in the second comment, I wasn't saying you wanted to quit. I was telling you that the variable `quit` referes to the function `quit`. Variable names *are not strings*.

Comment: Yh I know but when I assign quit() to a variable it will ask to quit when I don't want it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack trace says:

On line: `quit_program = input("<snip>")` it gets the error `NameError: name 'average' is not defined` *when you type in* `average`.

[`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) in Python2.7 runs whatever you type in (it's equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`. In this case, it's trying to run `average` which was user input. You want just [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

Then you want to compare that input to strings, as people have suggested:

```
quit_program = raw_input("Would you like the average or would you like to quit?")
if quit_program == "quit":
    quit()
elif quit_program == "average":
    print mean(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined quit and average.
You are checking for user input, which is a string.
Strings need "quotes" around them.
this is good:
    "I am a string"
This is bad:
    I am not a string

Comment: And just to be very clear, it could be either single or double quotes. `'I am a string'` or `"I am a string"` both work fine.

Comment: @FredLarson ok, i dont really use python so i didnt know about single quotes working aswell.